# Menu toggle not working when using not (this)

Tags: jquery

I'm building a basic dropdown menu, and when you click a menu item, I want make sure any open dropdowns close first.

Using not(this) on line two, allows toggleClass to toggle on, but off.

What am I missing?

```
$( '.nav-dropdown' ).click( function(){
  $( '.nav-dropdown-content' ).not( this ).addClass( 'hide' );
  $( '.nav-dropdown-content', this ).toggleClass( 'hide' );
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-dropdown">
      Menu Item 1 <span>&dtrif;</span>
      <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-dropdown">
      Menu Item 2 <span>&dtrif;</span>
      <div class="nav-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just turn them all off and then turn that one back on? `$( '.nav-dropdown-content').addClass( 'hide' ); $('.nav-dropdown-content', this).removeClass( 'hide' );`

Comment: please show relevant html structure. `this` isn't what you want it to be

Comment: Even addClass( 'hide' ) instead of not(this) seems to break the toggle

Comment: ^^^ We definitely need more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
 $( '.nav-dropdown' ).click( function(){
     var $content = $( '.nav-dropdown-content', this ).toggleClass( 'hide' );
     // exclude the current content instance
     $( '.nav-dropdown-content' ).not( $content ).addClass( 'hide' );      
});
```

`this` is the `$( '.nav-dropdown' )` element, so you can't use it as `not()` for `$( '.nav-dropdown-content' )`

Comment: you could also use `$(this).siblings().find('.nav-dropdown-content')` for the other ones